# Drop down text input option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a drop down element where user can select from available options or select enter value option which in turn allows to enter value.
I specifically want that user can enter value only when they select "Enter a value " option.

Here is what I have tried so far.

HTML-

```
<div class="ginput_container">
    <select name="input_4" id="input_1_4" class="medium gfield_select" tabindex="15">
       <option value="0">None</option>
       <option value="155">1-70</option>
       <option value="185">71-250</option>
       <option value="*">Enter value</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" value="None" class="holder" >
</div>
```

JavaScript-

```
jQuery(".gfield_select").change(function() {
        var val = jQuery(this).val();
        var enter = jQuery(this).parent().find('option:selected').text();
        var x = jQuery(this).parent();
        if (enter ==="Enter a value" || enter === "Enter value"){
          var holder = x.find('.holder');
          holder.val('');          
          holder.prop('disabled',false);
          holder.focus();
        } else {
          x.find('.holder').val(x.find('option:selected').text());
        }
});
```

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wTumv/1/)

however it wont work properly if i click the enter value option again.

Comment: tried anything so far?

Comment: tried different plugins but not exactly what i want.
I tried making this myself
http://jsfiddle.net/wTumv/1/

Comment: What is the problem you are having with implementing this, and specifically what do you need help with? Can you show us any code that you have tried so far? StackOverflow doesn't exist as a method for commissioning work - but for requesting help from expert peers with specific programming problems.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wTumv/1/

when i implement this it works fine except i wont be able to focus the textbox when i click enter value again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys
I guess i have found my answer

HTML-

```
<div class="ginput_container">
    <select name="input_4" id="input_1_4" class="medium gfield_select" tabindex="15">
       <option value="0">None</option>
       <option value="155">1-70</option>
       <option value="185">71-250</option>
       <option value="*">Enter value</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" value="None" class="holder" >
</div>
```

JavaScript-

```
jQuery(".gfield_select").change(function() {
var val = jQuery(this).val();
var enter = jQuery(this).parent().find('option:selected').text();
var x = jQuery(this).parent();
if (enter ==="Enter a value" || enter === "Enter value"){
  var holder = x.find('.holder');
  holder.val('');          
  holder.prop('disabled',false);
  holder.focus();
  jQuery(this).val("0"); // Change select value to None.
} else {
  x.find('.holder').val(x.find('option:selected').text());
  x.find('.holder').prop('disabled',true);
}
```

});

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wTumv/5/)

Answer (score 1):

I think there are many plugins that do what you want but if you want to create your own, it's a basic and simple solution.
You can create a `select` and a `textbox` with `display:none` like this:

```
<select id="ddlDropDownList">
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3</option>
    <option value="-1">Enter Value</option>
</select>
<input id="txtTextBox" type="text" />

<style>
    #txtTextBox{
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

then try this JQuery:

```
$("#ddlDropDownList").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == '-1'){
        $("#txtTextBox").fadeIn();
    }else{
        $("#txtTextBox").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qw91fqg5/2/)**

Comment: if you like to hide `select` and then `show` textbox so check this fiddle too : http://jsfiddle.net/qw91fqg5 (it's different to answer's demo)

Comment: thanks but it is not reusable. i did not want the select to dissapear.

Comment: i had made this one
http://jsfiddle.net/wTumv/1/ almost same logic as yours
but the only problem is i am not able to focus text box again if i enter select a value

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess i have found my answer.
http://jsfiddle.net/wTumv/5/

Answer (score 1):

I have forked your JSFiddle to http://jsfiddle.net/pwdst/4ymtmf7b/1/ which I hope does what you wanted to achieve.

HTML-

```
<div class="ginput_container">
    <label for="input_1_4">Select option</label>
    <select class="medium gfield_select" id="input_1_4" name="input_4" tabindex="15">        
        <option value="0">None</option>
        <option value="155">1-70</option>
        <option value="185">71-250</option>
        <option value="*">Enter value</option>
      </select>
      <div>
          <label class="hidden-label" for="input_1_4_other">Other value</label>
          <input class="holder" id="input_1_4_other" disabled="disabled" name="input_1_4_other" placeholder="None" type="text" />
     </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript-

```
jQuery(".gfield_select").change(function() {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        var val = $this.val();
        var holder = $this.parent().find('.holder');
        if (val === "*"){
            holder.val('');          
            holder.removeAttr('disabled');
            holder.focus();
        } else {           
            holder.val(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
            holder.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
});
```

When the "Enter value" option is chosen then the input box is enabled, value set to an empty string, and it is focused. If another option is chosen then the text input is disabled again, and the text value from the select list is used.